# How to debug iOS Handoff?

Tags: ios, handoff, nsuseractivity

I've added a small amount of code to my app which supposed to handle Handoff. Nothing fancy, just creating simple `NSUserActivity`, setting my `-[UIViewController userActivity]` property to it and make it current. And I did added proper `NSUserActivityTypes` array to my `Info.plist`, but still nothing works. My both devices logged in to the same iCloud account, and Safari Handoff works perfectly. I tried everything: my app icon does not appears on the other device lock screen. No errors, no warning, no nothing. How can I debug it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If nothing helps, try to see for suspicious messages in both of your devices console. In Xcode menu choose Window -> Devices, select one of your devices and look for anything related to Handoff.

In my case what I found was:

> ```
>  Jan 27 13:24:40 my-iphone useractivityd[1176] <Warning>: <NSXPCConnection: 0x145566b0> connection from pid 2012: Warning: Exception caught during decoding of received message, dropping incoming message.
>  Exception: decodeObjectForKey: class "UniversalLink" not loaded or does not exist
> ```

So my problem was: I was setting `-[NSUserActivity webpageURL]` to my *custom subclass* of `NSURL` named `UniversalLink`. I've changed it to pure `NSURL` and it worked perfectly ever since. Hope this help someone!